# How can I write a nat in the form of term?

Tags: coq

All

I am trying to complete the last execrise in the StlcProp of Software Foundations Vol2.
But I got stuck at defining **step**, in the rule ST_SuccNat.

```
Inductive step : tm -> tm -> Prop :=
  | ST_AppAbs : forall x T2 t1 v2,
      value v2 ->
      <{(\x:T2, t1) v2}> --> <{ [x:=v2]t1 }>
  | ST_App1 : forall t1 t1' t2,
      t1 --> t1' ->
      <{t1 t2}> --> <{t1' t2}>
  | ST_App2 : forall v1 t2 t2',
      value v1 ->
      t2 --> t2' ->
      <{v1 t2}> --> <{v1  t2'}>
  | ST_SuccNat: forall n:nat,
      <{succ n}> --> <{ S n }> (* <----- stuck here *)
```

Coq complains as below

```
In environment
step : tm -> tm -> Prop
n : nat
The term "S" has type "nat -> nat" while it is expected to have type "tm".
```

How can I tell Coq the `S n` in the form of "tm" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do

```
      <{succ n}> --> S n
(* which desugars to     succ (tm_const n) --> tm_const (S n) *)
```

The `<{` `}>` brackets change the interpretation of application. Here you want the regular function application, so don't use the brackets.